# cssフレームワーク「Materialize」でナビバーを作りたい

Tags: html, jquery, css

cssフレームワーク「Materialize」を使用して、サイト制作をしています。

テンプレートコード例があるので、それを見ながら作成しているのですが、 
ナビゲーションボタンのところで行き詰まってしまいました。

同サイトの[Showcase](http://materializecss.com/showcase.html)中にある下記サイトのように
「navバーをマウスオーバーすると1段組～4段組のメニューが展開する仕組み」を作りたいのです。

- https://artofwhere.com/
- http://emerald.sekizgen.net/

サイトを見たり、公式ホームページのテンプレートを見て解析したり試行錯誤もしたのですが、構造がよくわかりません。 
同フレームワークのみで出来ているのか、別にjavascriptやjQueryを使用しているのかなどもわからないです。 
英語の能力がほとんど無いせいもあるのですが、何かご助言頂けると幸いです。取り組み方でも、ここのテンプレートを参考にして、でも構いませんので、何か前にすすめるお手伝いをしいただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

> 同フレームワークのみで出来ているのか、別にjavascriptやjQueryを使用しているのかなどもわからないです。

どちらのサイトもMaterializeの機能は使用せずにjQueryを使用しているようです。

https://artofwhere.com/

jQuery-menu-aimを使用しているようです。

kamens/jQuery-menu-aim
https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim

```
    $("#nav").find(">ul").menuAim({
        rowSelector: "> li",
        submenuDirection: "below",
        activate: function(a) {
            var b = $(a).find(".subnav");
            b.show(),
            b.data("navTimeout_hide") && (clearTimeout(b.data("navTimeout_hide")),
            b.removeData("navTimeout_hide")),
            b.data("navTimeout_show", setTimeout(function() {
                b.addClass("hover")
            }, 20))
        },
        deactivate: function(a) {
            var b = $(a).find(".subnav");
            b.removeClass("hover"),
            b.data("navTimeout_show") && (clearTimeout(b.data("navTimeout_show")),
            b.removeData("navTimeout_show")),
            b.data("navTimeout_hide", setTimeout(function() {
                b.hide()
            }, 300))
        },
        exitMenu: function() {
            return !0
        }
    }),
```

http://emerald.sekizgen.net/

Superfishを使用しているようです。

Superfish
http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/

- `class`に`sf-menu`が指定されている
- bodyの閉じタグ直前に`superfish.js`が読み込まれている

---

> 英語の能力がほとんど無いせいもあるのですが、何かご助言頂けると幸いです。取り組み方でも、ここのテンプレートを参考にして、でも構いませんので、何か前にすすめるお手伝いをしいただければ幸いです。

今回は下記のように探しました。
今後のご参考になれば幸いです。
(使用ブラウザはChrome)

https://artofwhere.com/

1. 開発者ツールでメニューの要素を確認後、`bignav`や`subnav`でGoogle検索するも、なにも出ず
2. 開発者ツールで`bignav`のEvent Listenersタブでmouseoverを選択し、`master.min.js`の当該行に移動
3. jsがminify(圧縮)されているので、ツールの画面下にある`｛ ｝`ボタンをクリックして整形
4. 当該行(master.min.js:formatted#L9794)からはjQueryプラグインであることしかわからないので、ソースをCtrl + Fで検索(`nav`、`bignav`、`subnav` etc.)
5. 前記の引用コードが見つかるので、`menuAim`でGoogle検索

http://emerald.sekizgen.net/

開発者ツールでメニューの要素を確認後、`class`に指定されている`sf-menu`でGoogle検索

Comment: 詳細なご調査本当にありがとうございます。やってみます。探し方やたどりついた過程まで細かく教えていただいて、本当に助かりました。すばらしいご回答でした。今後とも宜しくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: artofwhere.comのサイトの方は、どうやらmaterializeを使っていないようで、私がサンプルで作っていたmaterializeのサイトにjQuery-menu-aimを組み込むと、クラス名がかぶっているのか、上手く表示されないようです。
Superfishで試してみます。